# Xcode has no accessibility label for MKMapView

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, accessibility

I'm running Xcode 8 and the Accessibility Inspector.  The Inspector complains that "Element has no description" for my `MKMapView`.  The Inspector's suggestion is to set the accessibilityLabel, but none exist for `MKMapView` in Interface Builder:

[image: Missing Accessibility Section]

Other type of elements do have an Accessibility section

Answer (score 1):

`MKMapView` is considered an accessibility container. If you inspect it's `isAccessibilityElement` at runtime, you'll see it's set to false. Only elements with `isAccessibilityElement` set to true can have an `accessibilityLabel`.

I'm also trying to look for a way to squash this audit warning. Looks like it's a bug in the Inspector.